# Exchange 2010: Job titles making it out of organization?

Tags: exchange, outlook-2010, privacy

I was asked a question from one of my co-workers that I was pretty sure about, but not 100% on.  Google didn't appear to help me out either, so here I am.

Do things like job titles and other such information make it out of Exchange 2010 when it's communicating with external mail servers?  I could see it happening if you sent someone a vcard or something similar, but I just wanted to be sure on it.

Thanks

Comment: Where are these titles at?  Are you talking about something in a signature, or just the properties of a users that are stored in the GAL/AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User information doesn't get sent out of Exchange unless the user has this information in their signature.

You are referring to sending emails, right?

Comment: Yep.  I had figured as much, but I was not sure.